# Adding a value to an existing array within a hash in powershell?

Tags: powershell

Say I have something like:

```
$funkyHash = @{
    "Z28" = @(13251, 13458, 78910)
    "Z14" = @(12356, 12348)
    "z15" = @(12344)
}
```

How do I for instance, pull out the `"z15"` array, add a value, lets say `456`, and make sure that it results in:

```
$funkyHash = @{
    "Z28" = @(13251, 13458, 78910)
    "Z14" = @(12356, 12348)
    "z15" = @(12344, 456)
}
```

...within funkyHash?

Comment: `$funkyHash['z15'] += 456`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried as per below, and seems working.

```
> $funkyHash

Name                           Value
----                           -----
z15                            {12344}
Z28                            {13251, 13458, 78910}
Z14                            {12356, 12348}
```

---

```
> $funkyHash["z15"] += @(999)
> $funkyHash

Name                           Value
----                           -----
z15                            {12344, 999}
Z28                            {13251, 13458, 78910}
Z14                            {12356, 12348}
```

Comment: But what are those enums?  I was trying for arrays.

Comment: ...or are they arrays?

Comment: The `$funkyHash` is a hash table of arrays of integer. Arrays: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-6#the-array-sub-expression-operator. Hash tables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-6